# how to implement update button for datagridview and save values to database using a dataHandler class(data access class) c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, data-handling

good day, hope everyone is well :)

I'm a first year student, and we just started with windows forms. I want to update data from `DataGridview` into my database using a button but I have to create an update method in a data handler `class` and call it in my form load, this is what I have tried so far.

DataHandler class:

```
        public void UpdateStudent(int number, string name, string surname, string dob, string gender, int phone, string address)
    {
        try
        {
            //string updateQuery = @"UPDATE Student SET number='" + number + "'name='" + name + "'surname='" + surname + "'dob='" + dob + "'gender'" + gender + "'phone='" + phone + "'address='" + address + "'";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("updated successfully....");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not updated!", ex.Message); m
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

update button on form load:

```
  DataHandler dh = new DataHandler();

 dh.UpdateStudent(int.Parse(txtStuID.Text), txtStuName.Text, txtStuSurname.Text,txtStuDOB.Text,txtStuGender.Text, int.Parse(txtStuNo.Text), txtStuAddress.Text);
```

Comment: One of the **first** things you should be learning then is about parametrisation. SQL Injection is something that should have died long ago; don't do it, it's a ***huge*** security vulnerability.

Comment: First thing is to implement SQL DBParameters.  They are not new, but required.  Secondly, it appears your "data access class" is an inner platform - add/change/delete are built in to the standard DB Provider tools as well as all the newer ones like ORMs

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Not to sound rude, but you should really start with your instructor.  Please review [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I would like to ask everyone not to be harsh in criticism. The asker is a beginner, like all of us were at some point and Casey even tried to solve the problem. It is too complicated now for Casey, because for a beginner everything seems to be complicated. The purpose of this site is to help people.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to initialize `SqlCommand`:

```
new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
```

You have missed passing any parameters. You will need to pass `updateQuery` as `queryString` and you will also need a proper connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual issues that brought you here are a couple of key issues with your SQL being invalid.  However, with that having been said, the comments regarding SQL injection are absolutely correct, and you would do well to learn about parameterized SQL.

First thing that jumps out is that your parameters need to be comma separated for this to be valid SQL.  The second thing is that you need to be identifying the row you wish to update with a WHERE clause, your current SQL statement is going to update every record in your table, not a single record.  Basically, your "number" field should not be in the list of columns to be updated, it needs to be moved to your WHERE clause.

Below is not a full solution to your homework assignment, but a snippet of the SQL with the issues corrected.  One thing you can do to help yourself as you learn is to try to get your SQL to compile and run *outside* of your program, and then implement it in your program once you have a working statement.

> UPDATE Student SET name = 'John', surname = 'Doe' WHERE number = 1